# wso2 identity server: Oauth 2.0 custom grant is not working for 5.11

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Creating custom Oauth 2.0 grant works for wso2is 5.9 (check following wso2is tutorial), but didn't work for wso2is 5.11  .I'm unable to view the new grant (I named it as "accessToken") under allowed grant during configuring new service provider (check screenshot).

Why custom grant is not working for wso2is 5.11? Please support.

tutorial compatible with 5.7, and works for 5.9:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Writinn;tg+a+Custom+OAuth+2.0+Grant+Type

1- custom grant jar location: wso2is-5.11\repository\components\lib\custom-grant-1.0.0.jar

2- xml tag added to /repository/conf/identity/identity.xml

```
<SupportedGrantType>
 <GrantTypeName>accesstoken</GrantTypeName>  
 <IdTokenAllowed>true</IdTokenAllowed>
 <GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>org.wso2.sample.identity.oauth2.grant.mobile.MobileGrant</GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>    
 <GrantTypeValidatorImplClass>org.wso2.sample.identity.oauth2.grant.mobile.MobileGrantValidator</GrantTypeValidatorImplClass>
</SupportedGrantType>
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding configs to /repository/conf/identity/identity.xml file, can you add the configs to <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml file as mentioned in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/writing-a-custom-oauth-2.0-grant-type/#resources and try

Answer (score 3):

Adding the mentioned XML tags to  `<IS-HOME>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml` won't work in IS-5.11.0 as it relies on new configuration model https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/references/new-configuration-model/

If you manually changed the identity.xml file, once the server is restarted, those configs should have reset to default. That should be the case not to show the new grant type under SP oauth configs.

So you have to change the deployment.toml file as follows

```
[[oauth.custom_grant_type]]
name="accesstoken"
grant_handler="org.wso2.sample.identity.oauth2.grant.mobile.MobileGrant"
grant_validator="org.wso2.sample.identity.oauth2.grant.mobile.MobileGrantValidator"
[oauth.custom_grant_type.properties]
IdTokenAllowed=true
```

Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/writing-a-custom-oauth-2.0-grant-type/#resources

NOTE: Always refer to the used product version documentation